# Log4j2 plugin not loaded in Spring 4

Tags: spring, annotations, log4j2, spring-restcontroller

While Spring 4 Rest application loading , i am getting the logger information ( log file name / path / archival days) from database and passing this value to Logj plugin , so that i can retrieve the value from log4j.xml.

My application log file not created and plugin not called !  not getting any error in console as well.
What should i do , for Logj plugin load and log file creation ?

```
Spring:4.3.15.RELEASE
log4j:2.4.1
java:1.8
```

SpringWebInitializer.java

```
 public class SpringWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    
    @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
              webCtx.register(WebConfiguration.class);
              webCtx.setServletContext(ctx);
              ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));
              servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
              servlet.addMapping("/");
              
              //Add Listener.
              ctx.addListener(new MyAppContextListner());
        
       }
    }
```

WebConfiguration.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="org.vasa.ws.myapp")
public class WebConfiguration {
    

}
```

MyAppContextListner.java

```
public class MyAppContextListner implements ServletContextListener{
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(BenefitsCompositeContextListner.class);
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = null;

     @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
              // Database connectivity and get the logger information from db.
    
           }
@Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }

}
```

> Given below Log4j Plugin i am using
> MyLog4JConfigDatabaseLookup.java

```
@Plugin(name = "MyAppdbLookup", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
    public class MyLog4JConfigDatabaseLookup extends AbstractLookup {
    
        public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
            System.out.println("Lookup......");
     
       }
    
    }
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration packages="org.vasa.ws.myapp">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="app-name">MyAppdbLookup</Property>
            <Property name="file-level">${MyAppdbLookup:logLevel}</Property>
            <Property name="log-file">${MyAppdbLookup:logFile}</Property>
            <Property name="log-file-level">${MyAppdbLookup:logLevel}</Property>  
            <Property name="log-path">${MyAppdbLookup:logPath}</Property>
            <Property name="archive-days">${MyAppdbLookup:archive-days}</Property>
            
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <Routing name="route-log">
                <Routes pattern="framework">
                    <Route key="benefitCompositeWS">
                        <RollingFile name="message-log" fileName="${log-path}/myapp.log" 
                                     filePattern="${log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/myapp.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" append="true">
                            <PatternLayout
                                    pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                            <Policies>
                                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="150 MB" />
                            </Policies>
                            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000">
                                <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="2">
                                    <IfFileName glob="*/myapp*.log.gz" />
                                    <IfLastModified age="${archive-days}" />
                                </Delete>
                            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                        </RollingFile >
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Routing>
    <Loggers>
            <Root level="${file-level}" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="route-log" />
                <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Comment: If your are using Log4j2 then your logging configuration file is incorrectly named.

Comment: file name is log4j2.xml and path is src/main/resources/

Comment: That’s not what the question says. Please correct it and check it again to make sure there are no other misleading mistakes.

Comment: How are you running the annotation processor? Can you confirm the appropriate meatadata is generated and packaged in your application?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - corrected .

Comment: using Maven plugin i am creating EAR file - This is Spring 4 Rest WS - it working fine. only log4j plugin not invoked nor log file created .

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my plugin name as lower case and now it's working fine as expected:

```
@Plugin(name="myappdblookup")
```